# jQuery - there is a class that I can't detect

Tags: jquery, class

I am using jQuery and in order to detect the empty fields in the form I'm adding the class "l_invalids" when clicking on the submit button.

When clicking on the submit button I have the following code:

```
$("#myform :input").find(".l_invalids").each(function(){
    alert("hi");
});

if($(".l_invalids")){
    alert("Please correct the RED fields before submitting the form");
    return false;
}
```

Right after loading the page and pressing on the submit button the message "Please correct the RED fields before submitting the form" appear although I don't see any 'l_invalids' classes (in the chrome inspect).
Although I can see 1 match (in chrome) for l_invalids in the search field (not the 'find' option).

I tried to rename the class name but with the same problem.

Can you please assist?

Thanks!

Comment: please post your html code that contains the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".l_invalids")
```

This is a jQuery selection. jQuery selections never evaluate to boolean `false` in an `if` statement, even if they are empty. You need to test to see if there are any elements in the selection with the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
if ($(".l_invalids").length) {
```

This returns the number of elements in the selection. If it is `0`, the condition fails, because `0` evaluates to boolean `false`. Any other number – i.e. a non-empty selection – evaluates to boolean `true`, so the condition will pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
if($(".l_invalids").length > 0){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the at this condition checking :

```
if($(".l_invalids")){
     ....
```

$(".l_invalids") will alway return a JQuery Object, and an object will always be "true". Use the length property of the JQuery object instead :

```
if($(".l_invalids").length > 0){
   ...
```

or just simple :

```
if($(".l_invalids").length){
   ...
```